# How to load youtube website in Android WebView?

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I have a very simple WebView implementation, it works well in almost all websites, but when it comes to youtube, I can load the home page, video page, but when I click play button (on page m.youtube.com/index?desktop_uri=%2F&gl=US#/watch?v=xxxxxx), the video flash but does not play. My android version is 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

first update your flash player  ....

second  check for permission like you have  given for internet or not in androidMenifest file

third

i dont know why but webviewclient class causes the problem , we can run it in default browser remove the webviewclient class and simly load the url of youtube you will be able to run it on 2.2,2.3

```
    w=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    w.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    w.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");
```

for 2.1 just add this, use intent and through parse method open it through default    installed  youtube application

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/v/%s")))); }

Comment: did u tried what prob did u got  the above code works i  was facing same problem   and i come to above result after lot of research